# redirect urls using htaccess from

Tags: .htaccess

I need to redirect urls using htaccess from

http://www.example.com/showthread.php?t=1
to http://www.example.com/threads/1/

and from http://www.example.com/showthread.php?t=1&page=2 
to http://www.example.com/threads/1/page-2

Comment: I would recommend editing your post to include what you have attempted up to this point.

Comment: i want to use htaccess to redirect url from vbulletin script
to urls in post

Comment: What you want is clear. Whether or not you have put any effort of your own toward that goal is not clear. People are more likely to help users who have tried, in earnest, to help themselves. Showing users what solutions you have attempted is a show of good faith that you are not trying to have others simply do the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below rules :

```php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase / 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/showthread\.php$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^t=([0-9]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /thread/%1/ [R=301,L,QSD]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/showthread\.php$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^t=([0-9]+)&page=([0-9]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /thread/%1/page-%2 [R=301,L,QSD]
```

Comment: i tested it and get
Not Found
The requested URL /showthread.php was not found on this server.